# Find the direction cosines of the a vector in the plane of $\vec b=<2, 1, 3>$ and $\vec c=<-1, 2, 1>$ and perpendicular to $\vec c$

Tags: vectors

Let the vector $\vec a =\langle x, y, z\rangle$

Since it is perpendicular to $\vec c$
$$-x+2y+z=0$$

And $$\begin{vmatrix} x &y&z \\ 2&1&3 \\ -1&2&1 \end{vmatrix}$$

$$\implies -5x-7y+5z=0$$ since a, b, c are coplanar

So $y=0$

Then $x=y$

So the answer should be $\left\langle\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right\rangle$ , but that is not correct.

What is wrong with my solution?

The answer is $\left \langle\frac{15}{\sqrt {369}} , 0, \frac{12}{\sqrt {369}} \right \rangle $

Comment: mind a slight mistake you should get $-5x-5y+5z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the unknow vector be $\vec a =(x,y,z)$ since $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ are coplaner their box product must vanish $$\implies \vec a. (\vec b \times \vec c)=0 \implies -5x-5y+5z=0 ~~~~(1)$$ Next the perpendicularity of $\vec a$ and $\vec c$ gives $vec a. \vec c=0 \implies -x+2y+z=0~~~~(2)$
From (1)(2) we get $y=0, x=z$, hence $\vec a= (x,0,x)$ $$ \implies \vec a= \frac{(1,0,1)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec r=p \vec b+ q \vec c$, take dot product of this with $\vec c$, and use $\vec r. \vec c=0$, then
$$\vec r. \vec c\vec =p \vec b. \vec c+q\vec c. \vec c \implies p=-q \frac{c^2}{\vec b. \vec c}=-q \frac{6}{3}=-2q.$$
So the required vector $\vec r$ is:
$$\vec r=q[-2\vec b+ \vec c]=q(-5\vec i- 5\vec k).$$
$q$ is arbitrary real number. Next $\hat r= \frac{\vec i+\vec k}{\sqrt{2}}$

It also means that $$\vec r= \alpha~ \vec c \times(\vec b \times \vec c),$$
namely, the vector triple product.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the projection of $\vec b$ onto the direction perpendicular to $\vec c$ is

$$\vec b - (\vec b\cdot\vec c)\frac{\vec c}{|c|^2}
= <2, 1, 3>- \frac12<-1, 2, 1>=<\frac52,0,\frac52>
$$
Normalize to get $\vec a = <\frac1{\sqrt2},0,\frac1{\sqrt2}>$.

Comment: I added the answer, please check